# What does ビクビクのヌルヌルで mean?

Tags: meaning, particle-の

What does ビクビクのヌルヌルで mean?

As for context, she was trying to remove the fish she had just caught from her fishing rod. It's clear that she's referring to the fish, but the の between ビクビク and ヌルヌル is confusing me as to what is being said.

Comment: I think ヌルヌル means slimy/slippery. [source](http://jisho.org/search/nurunuru)

Comment: Slippery is ツルツル.

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the comment section and in the other answer, ヌルヌル means "slimy", "slippery" and hard to grab hold of.

ビクビク often means "to feel scared", but here in your example it has nothing to do with "feeling scared". 明鏡国語辞典 explains びくびく as follows:

> びくびく〘副詞〙 ❶ 恐怖・不安に敏感になっておびえるさま。 ❷ 体などが何度もふるえ動くさま。

We use ビクビク, ビクッ, or ビクン to describe a sudden and violent convulsive movement, as well as a 痙攣 (convulsion, twitch, cramp), so the ビクビク here is more like "to wriggle" or "to twitch", and indicates the sudden and quick movement of the fish. Here're a few examples of this use of ビクビク:

> - [「睡眠中に足や腕が**ビクビク**と動く」](http://www.xendela.info/2015/06/PLMS.html)
> - [「寝ているときに体がピクッと動いたり**ビクビク**動いたりする」](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1073472505)
> - [「動かなかった魚が、**ビクビク**！！って動きます」](http://worldchefsbible.com/%E5%85%83%E7%A5%96%E3%80%81%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%99%E7%90%86/%E9%AD%9A%E3%81%AE%E5%8D%B8%E3%81%97%E6%96%B9/)

The の here is used to connect the two mimetic words, like "and". You can rephrase ビクビクのヌルヌルで as ビクビク**で**(その上)ヌルヌルで or ビクビク**していて**(その上)ヌルヌルしていて, "The fish was wriggling **and** slimy". To me, ビクビク**の**ヌルヌル sounds a little more emphatic than normal ビクビク**で**ヌルヌル.

I couldn't find the definition of this use of の in a paper or online dictionary. 
I'll just quote a couple of examples from the web:

> - 「[道路(が)つるつる**の**てかてか！](http://ameblo.jp/2525toshi/entry-10723231640.html)」
> - 「[金属をつるつる**の**ピカピカにする](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1030000360)」
> - 「[ギタギタ**の**メロメロ**の**ボロボロにしてやる。](http://www5e.biglobe.ne.jp/~poh/jaianizm-2.htm)」

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's strictly G-rated (Doraemon, Anpan-man, ...), I'd guess that some suggestive humor is intended.

Do a search with　 [　ビクビク  and  ヌルヌル　]　 and you'll see ...

https://www.google.co.jp/#q=%E3%83%93%E3%82%AF%E3%83%93%E3%82%AF++++%E3%83%8C%E3%83%AB%E3%83%8C%E3%83%AB

```
     ( Every one of the top 50 hits is explicit material. )
```

I didn't realize that the expression ビクビク感じちゃう had become so common.

```
     Ok, i now see that strictly G-rated manga, novel, story, etc.
     would never use the combination  [　ビクビク  and  ヌルヌル　]
```

---

並立助詞　ヘイリツジョシ ......... 現代語では、「と」「に」「か」「や」「やら」「の」「だの」など、古語では「や」「の」など。並列助詞。

```
          出典 浮世風呂　滑稽   「着物がきたねの、貧乏人だのと」
```

http://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E/%E6%A0%BC%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E%E3%82%92%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86/

```
    (4)　並立語を表す（並立格）     「の」「に」「と」「や」がつく文節は、並立語になる。 
               （例）生きる の 死ぬ の と大騒ぎをする。 
                     行く の 行かない の とはっきりしない。
```

---

Re: chocolate's comments (below).  -- (I still have to re-read them.) --  chocolate's comments are excellent.

As chocolate says, I think they may be different.

- 四の五の言うな (四だの五だの言うな ?)  -- This is just a list of examples (connected by OR ?)
- 「ギタギタ の メロメロ の ボロボロ にしてやる。」 -- Jaian (Gian) is saying [ I'll make you ... AND ... AND ... ! ]

Comment: 並立助詞「の」の「～の～のと」「～だの～だのと」の例文は「着物が汚ねえ**だ**の、貧乏人**だ**のと」「生きる**だ**の死ぬ**だ**のと、大騒ぎをする」「行く**だ**の行かない**だ**のとはっきりしない」と言い換え可能ですし、引用の「と」がついていて引用の意味があり「着物が汚い(だ)とか貧乏人(だ)とか」「生きる(だ)とか死ぬ(だ)とか言って大騒ぎする」とも言い換えられます。しかし、「ビクビク**の**ヌルヌルで」「つるつる**の**ピカピカにする」などは、二つ目の語の後に「の」がなく、「～の～のと」にも「～だの～だの」にも「～だの～だのと」にも言い換えられませんし、引用の意味もなく「～とか～とか言って」にもできません。また、ピッチアクセントが違い、「～の～の」の場合「[生きるの死ぬの]{LHLLLHL}と」「[行くの行かないの]{LHLLHHLL}と」と「の」が低いのに対し、「[ピカピカの]{LHHHHH}つるつる」などの「の」は高いです。これらのことから、辞書に載っている「～の～のと」「～だの～だのと」の用法とは異なるものだと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: "As chocolate says, I think they may be different". The one you mention is similar to a nominalizing の, the one in the OP is more akin to a "genitive" の.