# Usage of の in 食い放題の飲み放題

Tags: grammar, particle-の

I'm not sure what the usage of の in this sentence is?

> でかい業務用冷蔵庫を開けりゃ何でもある。 何でも食い放題**の**飲み放題。

と makes sense to me as in「何でも食い放題と飲み放題」but why is の used here instead?

[image]

Comment: Where is this from? Could this be a typo?

Comment: I found it while playing a game. I don't think it could be a typo.

Comment: Could you give more context, and if possible, a screenshot? I just want to rule out the possibility of a misidentification, because 食べ放題の飲み放題 really makes no sense to me.

Comment: Actually, I have a theory: since 飲み放題 starts with 飲{の}, could it be when the developer was typing he just accidentally typed の twice?

Comment: These seem related: [Meaning of の in the の、の と pattern (どうのこうの)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68618/43676), [What does ビクビクのヌルヌルで mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38266/43676).

Comment: Are they related? 食い放題 and 飲み放題 are not mimetic words and its not in the「～の～の」form?

Comment: @aguijonazo is right. they're both used to enumerate adjectives.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a definition for this in dictionaries, but I think this の is an emphatic listing particle. It's used between two similar words that describe a quality or state of something. It's typically used between two mimetic words ([example](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38266/5010)), but it can be used with other na-/no-adjectives.

- イベントは最高の最強だった。
- 最低の最悪な話を聞いた。
- 服が泥まみれの埃まみれになっている。
- こちらのパンは焼きたての熱々です。
- ガチのマジで危なかった。
- 本気の本気で頑張ります。
  <sup>(The same word is used twice for emphasis)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

の is used to enumerate verbs and adjectives and 食い放題の飲み放題 enumerates two adjectives: 食い放題 and 飲み放題.

> （主に用言につけて）列挙する。だの。

> 狭いの暗いのって文句ばかりつける。

> 言ったの言わないのと揉めていた。

Ref: https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AE